# Heroku: Bunch of npm errors on deployment

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

I have a bunch of npm errors in my heroku logs. How can I begin to debug this? thanks!

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFSpw.png)
package.json

```
{
 "name": "server",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "",
 "main": "index.js",
 "engines": {
 "node": "8.1.1",
 "npm": "5.0.3"
},
 "scripts": {
 "start": "node index.js"
},
 "author": "",
 "license": "ISC",
 "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.0"
 }
}
```

Comment: Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you already tried yourself to find the problem? Stack Overflow is not a debugging services. Questions should show **evidence of research and attempts to solve the problem yourself**, a clear outline of your specific coding-related issue, and any relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we have enough information to be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

**NPM ERR: missing script: start**

It seems like you're missing the "start" script in your package.json file. That's where I would start looking. Heroku might assume you've set this script up beforehand. Here's a sample package.json file with the start script:

```
{
    "name": "your-app",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": { // your npm scripts go here
        "start": "nodemon index.js", // or whatever server package you're using
        "lint:js": "node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js ./ ./**/*.js --fix; exit 0",
        "lint:css": "node_modules/csslint/cli.js public/css/; exit 0",
        "test": "NODE_ENV=test node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha"
    },
    "more": "settings below"
}
```

Here's a blurb from the Heroku website:

> **Specifying a start script**
>
> To determine how to start your app, Heroku first looks for a Procfile. If no Procfile exists for a Node.js app, we will attempt to start a default web process via the start script in your package.json.
> The command in a web process type must bind to the port number specified in the PORT environment variable. If it does not, the dyno will not start.
> For more information, see Best Practices for Node.js Development and Heroku Node.js Support.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs